# Cant connect to sqlite databases in java using java.sql

Tags: java, database, jdbc, classpath

I'm trying to establish a connection to my SQLite database. However, I always get the same exception when trying to run the file. Here's my code:

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainProgram extends Application{
    private Label label2 = new Label("");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("YTCCT");
        Label label1 = new Label("YT-Content Creation Tool");
        TextField Inputfeld1 = new TextField();
        Inputfeld1.setPromptText("Content Input");
        Button button1 = new Button("Idea convertion");
        VBox Mainlayout = new VBox(label1, Inputfeld1, button1, label2);
        Scene window = new Scene(Mainlayout, 300, 500);
        stage.setScene(window);
        stage.show();
        button1.setOnAction(event -> {
            String Inputstring = Inputfeld1.getText();
            try {
                ideaconvertion(Inputstring);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    private void ideaconvertion(String idea) throws SQLException {
        String url; 
        url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/ContentCreationToolYT/src/Ideadatabase.db";
        Connection connection1 = null;
        try {
            connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String sql1 = "INSERT INTO Ideas (spaltenname) VALUES (?)";
            Statement statement1 = connection1.createStatement();
            //statement1.executeQuery(sql1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            label2.setText("Error with connecting to the idea database");
        }
    }

}
```

This is the exception that always occurs when I try to execute my method:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for C:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/ContentCreationToolYT/src/Ideadatabase.db
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:706)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:252)
    at Project/contentcreationtool.fx.MainProgram.ideaconvertion(MainProgram.java:55)
    at Project/contentcreationtool.fx.MainProgram.lambda$0(MainProgram.java:43)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8875)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@21.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3984)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2708)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Also its important that I provide information to the JDBC JAR classpath:

I use the sqlite-jdbc-3.44.1.0.jar and its configured in my project in the library classpath. There I added it as an external JAR.

Upon research, there were a few ideas that I've tried. For example, I tried to change my URL to the given database.

1. `jdbc:sqlite:D:\\\\db\\\\Ideadatabase.db`
2. `jdbc:sqlite:Ideadatabase.db`

Comment: You need to provide a JDBC URL, not just the path to the file, for example (guessing) `jdbc:sqlite:<filepath>`, not just `<filepath>` that you're using in the code (and when producing the error). Consult the documentation of the driver you're using for the correct URL. And if you still get a _"No suitable driver found for ..."_ error when using the right URL syntax, then the driver is not on the runtime classpath. Please show how you run your code.

Comment: As an aside, although `jdbc:sqlite:D:\\\\db\\\\Ideadatabase.db` looks like a valid path, it might fail because you're using too many backslash you need a single backslash as a separator, which in a string literal is represented by two backslash, not four (though if I forget if Windows is lenient with that or not).

Comment: I now used this path "jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/ContentCreationToolYT/src/Ideadatabase.db". However, i still get the same result.

Comment: If that is the right URL syntax, then you don't have the driver on the runtime classpath, or you're using a very old version which needs to be explicitly loaded with `Class.forName` (i.e. it doesn't support automatic driver loading). As I said, show exactly how you run your code. Though 3.44.1.0 is the latest version and does support automatic driver loading, so you probably just don't have it on the runtime classpath.

Comment: How can i show in the comment section, how i exactly run my code?

Comment: You don't, you should [edit] the question and show the commandline used.

Comment: My programm consists of a user interface which also contains a textfield. The string that i type into the textfield then is being transferred into the database. At least thats what i intend to do. But the exception occurs when i try to transfer the strings into the database, using the drivermanager.

Comment: I'm asking how you **run** your program, that is what `java` commandline is used to run it.